# How does <%= f.submit %> know where to post?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

While messing on rails I coded this:

```
<%= form_for :creature, url: "/creatures", method: "post" do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  <%= f.submit "save creature" %>
<% end %>
```

I clearly understand where this posts. **However** I found this also works:

```
<%= form_for @creature do |f| %>

  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.text_area :description %>
  <%= f.submit "save creature", class: "btn btn-default"%>

<% end %>
```

I ran through the folders on my rails app, and I know that it's still posting to this endpoint **post '/creatures' => 'creatures#create'**. And I want to know how on earth the second block of code knows to still post to that endpoint. Moving from Node.JS to Rails is a bit mind bending.

Here is my controller for the curious:

```
class CreaturesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @creatures = Creature.all
  end

  def new
    @creature = Creature.new
  end

  def create
    new_creature = params.require(:creature).permit(:name, :description)
    creature = Creature.create(new_creature)
    redirect_to "/creatures/#{creature.id}"
  end

  def show
    id = params[:id]
    @creature = Creature.find(id)
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `form_for` helper interprets the model given to it (in this case `@creature`) and uses rails conventions to calculate the route. Look at the generated html form.

See the docs here for more info: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: It's mind boggling how, idk how to put this, "smart?" rails is. I'm so used to things breaking messing around with Express and Mongo, and in Rails things kind've just... work. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Rails make a form use `form builder` so every object or url will generate the url default.

> To create a form within this template, you will use a form builder.
>   The primary form builder for Rails is provided by a helper method
>   called form_for. To use this method, add this code into

You can get more information here [form builder rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#the-first-form)

Answer (score 1):

`<%= f.submit %>` doesn't know anything about where or what to POST. That just creates a submit tag in the form.

The important bit is the `form_for` helper (you can also use `form_tag` for non-resourceful forms). It can create the  path for the form action from the resource for you, and has parameters for specifying the method (POST, GET, etc).

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object

Comment: Rails just seem so powerful and developer friendly. Makes me feel uneasy in a a way, haha. So for this line

_In short, you can just pass the model instance and have Rails figure out model name and the rest._ 

Is there somewhere I can read how rails figures that part out? Or is that abstracted away from me and I just take the rails conventions for what they are? Is that better practice for ruby on rails?

Answer (score 1):

The key method involved here is `polymorphic_path`

This method looks at whether the object is a new record or not (via the `persisted?` method) and then looks at the object's `model_name` property to find out the name used for routes (this is part of the ActiveModel interface that objects need to conform to for `form_for` to be able to figure things like this out automatically).

From this, `polymorphic_path` knows that it needs to use `creatures_path` to build the URL. If the object had been saved the. It would have called `creature_path` instead, passing the creature as an argument.

Separately `form_for` knows that the method should be POST since the object is unsaved.

Answer (score 1):

`f.submit` is just as intelligent as the `submit` button for a [standard HTML form](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp).

Remember, Rails' [form helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html) (as well as the other HTML helpers) are just ways to output HTML. As such, `f.submit` simply creates a `submit` button. The real "magic" happens in the HTML form's `action` attribute:

```
<form action="url/for/action">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

--

In order to understand how Rails "knows" where to send requests after form submission, you need to appreciate the *RESTful* nature of Rails' routes.

You've seen routes like this:

```
#config/routes.rb
resource :controller
```

This creates a series of *resourceful* routes, which are built around objects.

As such, when you use the likes of `form_for`, it expects an object which it can apply its own routing to. IE if your object is a `new` object, it will push to the `create` path; if it's populated, it will send to the `update` path.

You'll gain a lot by reading up on the [`form_for` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html).